# SQLite order by Date with format EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy

Tags: android, sqlite

My date is being saved as a string in sqlite in the format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy". it is quite important that is saved this way.

However, now I need to fetch the saved data from database whilst ordering them by date starting with the newest.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + InteractionSchema.TABLE +
                     " interaction " + " WHERE interaction." +
                     InteractionSchema.KEY_owner +
                     " =? ORDER BY datetime(" + InteractionSchema.KEY_date +
                     ") DESC LIMIT 15";
```

It is not working at all, I tried using all the other [SQLite date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)  but to no avail. I am pretty sure it has to do with the date format. Has anybody dealt with this before? (PS, it is not a duplicate I have already gone through similar questions on stackoverflow)

Comment: `it is quite important that is saved this way.` ... This format will cause problems in SQL.  Why is this important?  I would rather store the date in a standard format `yyyymmdd` and generate your version when querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always save dates as UTC timestamps (`INTEGER`) in SQLite on Android devices. This way you can easily compare and sort them and they use less storage space.

Then nothing prevents you from formatting the date back to its original format using a `SimpleDateFormat`.

If the timezone is important to preserve (let's say you want the dates to be always formatted according to the timezone of a specific country instead of using the default locale), then you can save the UTC offset in a separate column next to the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show datetime and also want to be able to sort the data without extra processings, you can have two columns TEXT and INTEGER where you can store formatted date in TEXT column and time in mills in INTEGER column and have you data sorted based on INTEGER data. This way you can achieve both things.

Comment: Dates in SQLite are basically just strings.

Comment: If you save date as string then Order by function will not work. Its better to store date as data type DATETIME or have kind of _id column which is auto incremented rowid which can be easily sorted.

Comment: There is no DATETIME type in sqlite, date as string in yyyyMMdd format can be ordered and androidhive is a bad tutorials site

Comment: If you want to show datetime and also want to be able to sort the data without extra processings, you can have two columns TEXT and INTEGER where you can store formatted date in TEXT column and time in mills in INTEGER column and have you data sorted based on INTEGER data. This way you can achieve both things.